# how to get the selected cell in <p:dataTable primefaces?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to get, if possible, the selected cell or colomne (id) of primefaces `<p:dataTable`

my table is like :

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="list" value="#{bean.list}" rowKey="#{list}" selectionMode="single" >
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.onRowSelect}" />
    <p:column headerText="Date" >
        <h:outputText  value="#{list.SDate}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name" >
        <h:outputText value="#{list.IName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

with this method I can get the row selected (line) using `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.onRowSelect}" />`
but I can't get the selected colomn "`Date`" or "`Name`"

onrowSelecte method is like :

```
 public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)
        myObject obj = (myObject)event.getObject();
        //.......
 }
```

Comment: can you show us `onRowSelect` method in the bean?

Comment: @SrinivasR see edit, thk you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the value of the specific column

```
<p:dataTable id="firsttable" var="list" value="#{bean.list}" rowKey="#{list}" selectionMode="single" >
     <p:column headerText="Date" >
        <h:outputText  value="#{list.SDate}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name" >
        <h:outputText value="#{list.IName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

// This is capture the value of selected column
<h:inputText id="selectedId" value="#{bean.selectedColumn}" style="display:none">
       <f:ajax listener="#{bean.onRowSelect}"></f:ajax>
</h:inputText>
```

This script captures the values of the selected row and sets the inputHidden

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
    $(window).load(function () {
         $(document).delegate("#firsttable td", "click", function (event) {
             var columnNumber = jQuery(this).index();//get index of clicked row
         var colval=jQuery(this).find('div span').text()); // get the column value
         $("#selectedId").val(colval); //set value in the inputtext
         $("#selectedId").change(); //this will trigger the ajax listener
       });
    });
```

And In the bean define property to get the input text value

```
 String selectedColumn;

 public void onRowSelect(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
         String value=getSelectedColumn();
         System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: the script dosnt work for me. I get this error in  'jQuery.noConflict();' : Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function script.js.xhtml:159
(anonymous function)

Comment: fast solution is perfect !! thank you friend. just to get the jsf inputId we must use  $("#form\\:selectedId") !!!!

Comment: Yeah.`$("#form\\:selectedId") ` you have to use this when you have a formId.But I did as per `<h:form prependId="false">` to avoid confusion

Comment: I have a problem !! the jquery function is called all time when i click of any table. how to specifie one table only?

Comment: @berber5..Yes that happens cause in the above script event is `delegated` to `table td`.You can assign a `id` to the table and do `.delegate('#tableid td','click'....)`.see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Karim,

I think you are forgetting add **update** on your ajax event:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.onRowSelect}" update="table" />
```

On `update` you need put your table id or element that encapsulates your table.

If the table is inside outputPanel, you can update it id instead the table.

> The `update` attribute it is necessary for send the screen information
>   to your backBean.

I hope it heps...

Good Luck!

Comment: Thx for answer ! Rolo :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think primefaces has anything to select a column , you may need to add something like

```
<h:outputText  value="#{list.SDate}" >
<f:ajax event="select" listener="#{bean.setSelectedColumn}"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Use event.getComponent() to further determine which column is selected

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.
I want to get the selected colomn  "DATE​​" or "NAME"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding PrimeFaces DataTable, widgetVar, Javascript, jQuery:

I had trouble using Primefaces widgetVar to get the selected row of a PrimeFaces 3.5 DataTable.  I looked through the PF source here...

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js?r=10301

...and also used Chrome debugger to examine the DataTable, but did not find a getSelectedRow method.  I probably missed something useful, but here is my hack, which works.

`var selectedRow = Array();`

`$('#idForm1\\:idDT tr.ui-state-highlight').each(function(i) {
    $(this).children('td').each(function(ii) {
        selectedRow.push($(this).text());
    });
 });`

Array selectedRow is populated with the `<td>` text values of the selected DataTable row.